# Key requesting fails

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I was following as directed in the video for TBB(3.6.4) verification for MacOSX.
But the step where we do: gpg --keyserver x-hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 0x63FEE659
is not proceeding further. It says like:

gpg: requesting key 63FEE659 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Keyserver error
nothing:Downloads SUDDU$

or like:

gpg: requesting key 63FEE659 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Keyserver error
You have mail in /var/mail/SUDDU
nothing:Downloads SUDDU$

So what now?